# How To Get Most Frequent Words With Association In PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the most frequent search word With Association Rules.

the php code contains two files. In which data is inserted every input is storing in the file along with its association for example :- **if some one has search "apple" and he has also searched for "orange". Now I want to get the most frequent searched words.**

I have got the frequency of the words but now i want to show top 10 frequent words with their association

```
<?php
    $item = file('item.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
    $data = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );



    $item_array = array();

    foreach ($item as $value) {
        $total_per_item[$value] = 0;
        foreach($data as $item_data) {            
            if(strpos($item_data, $value) !== false) {
                $total_per_item[$value]++;
            }
        }
    }

        echo "<pre>";
    echo "Occurrance";
    print_r($total_per_item);

    $item1 = count($item) - 1; // minus 1 from count
    echo $item1."<br/>";
    $item2 = count($item); // minus 1 from count
    echo    $item2."<br/>";
    $item_loop = (pow($item1,2) + $item1) / 2;
            echo $item_loop;



    for($i = 0; $i < $item1; $i++) {
        for($j = $i+1; $j < $item2; $j++) {
            $item_array[$item[$i].'-'.$item[$j]] = 0;

            foreach($data as $item_data) {
            if((strpos($item_data, $item[$i]) !== false) && (strpos($item_data, $item[$j]) !== false)) {
                    $item_array[$item[$i].'-'.$item[$j]]++;
                }
            }

                                echo $item_array[$item[$i].'-'.$item[$j]]++."<br/>";

        }
    }

                    print_r($item_array);           

    ?>
```

file.txt contains following data

```
Milk
Butter
Bread
Oil
Cheese
Burger
```

data.txt contains following data:-

```
   Milk,Butter
    Butter,Oil
    Burger,Milk
    Milk,Cheese
    Oil,Butter
    Burger,Oil
```